# Corrupt patch error nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, compilation, cross-compiling, patch

I try to compile nodejs for armv7 and before to do `~/cross-compiler-shell.sh and ./configure && make install` , i must patch this script but `git apply wscript` returns me the error

> fatal: corrupt patch at line 49

Here is my patch:

```
--- a/deps/libev/wscript
+++ b/deps/libev/wscript
@@ -41,6 +41,7 @@ def configure(conf):
 conf.check_cc(header_name="sys/eventfd.h", function_name="eventfd")


+  ''' Can't run cross-binary code
code = """
   #include <syscall.h>
   #include <time.h>
@@ -54,6 +55,8 @@ def configure(conf):
"""
conf.check_cc(fragment=code, define_name="HAVE_CLOCK_SYSCALL", execute=True,
             msg="Checking for SYS_clock_gettime")
+  '''
+  conf.define('HAVE_CLOCK_SYSCALL', 1)

have_librt = conf.check(lib='rt', uselib_store='RT')
if have_librt:


vim wscript

--- a/wscript
+++ b/wscript
@@ -319,11 +319,15 @@ def v8_cmd(bld, variant):
if bld.env['DEST_CPU'] == 'x86_64':
 arch = "arch=x64"

+ cross_arch = False
+ # TODO would use -1 != str.find('linux-gnueabi'), but this is sometimes a string and other times an array
+ # if bld.env['AR'] == 'arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ar':
+ #   arch = "arch=arm"
+ #   cross_arch = True
+ # 
+ arch = "arch=arm"
+ cross_arch = True

if variant == "default":
 mode = "release"
else:
 mode = "debug"

+  snapshot = 'snapshot=on'
+  if cross_arch:
+    snapshot = ''
-  cmd_R = 'python "%s" -j %d -C "%s" -Y "%s" visibility=default mode=%s %s library=static snapshot=on'
+  cmd_R = 'python "%s" -j %d -C "%s" -Y "%s" visibility=default mode=%s %s library=static ' + snapshot
```

I've tried to put a blank line at the end but error stays here.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this the full patch file? It does not even have 51 lines

Comment: Sorry, i've put the wrong number, it is 49, i've corrected

Comment: It also has not 49 lines, but only 48

Comment: Sure, gedit says me 48 too but the git apply command returns me error on line 49

Comment: Well, gedit doesn't show me the blankline at the end but emacs is fine so i've removed the blankline at the end and the error now says me on line 48

Answer (score 1):

Your patch metadata is incorrect as you probably manually mangled with the patch. `@@ -319,11 +319,15 @@ def v8_cmd(bld, variant):` should actually be `@@ -319,10 +319,20 @@ def v8_cmd(bld, variant):`.

Comment: Thanks, error disapear but i do that cause we say to me that it may be the cause of another problem but it still here, when i launch './configure' command for configure nodejs before make, i got syntaxerror on line 3 of this script cause of @@

Comment: I'm sorry, but that english was so horrible that I have no idea what you are saying. But it sounds to me like a different question as this was about applying of the corrupt patch file.